# Compass/Lucene in clustered environment

Tags: lucene, compass-lucene

I get the following error in a clustered environment where one node is indexing the objects and the other node is confused about the segments that are there in cache. The node never recovers by itself even after server restart. The node that's indexing might be merging the segments and deleting which the other node is not aware of. I did not touch the invalidateCacheInterval setting and added compass.engine.globalCacheIntervalInvalidation property with 500ms. It didn't help.

This is happening while searching and indexing on the other node.

Can someone help me how to resolve this issue? Maybe to ask compass reload the cache or start from scratch without having to reindex all the objects?

org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to search with query [+type:...)]; nested exception is org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.JdbcStoreException: No entry for [_6ge.tis] table index_objects
org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.JdbcStoreException: No entry for [_6ge.tis] table index_objects
        at org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.index.FetchOnBufferReadJdbcIndexInput$1.execute(FetchOnBufferReadJdbcIndexInput.java:68)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.support.JdbcTemplate.executeSelect(JdbcTemplate.java:112)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.index.FetchOnBufferReadJdbcIndexInput.refill(FetchOnBufferReadJdbcIndexInput.java:58)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.ConfigurableBufferedIndexInput.readByte(ConfigurableBufferedIndexInput.java:27)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexInput.readVInt(IndexInput.java:78)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermBuffer.read(TermBuffer.java:64)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermEnum.next(SegmentTermEnum.java:127)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermEnum.scanTo(SegmentTermEnum.java:158)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReader.get(TermInfosReader.java:250)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReader.get(TermInfosReader.java:218)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.docFreq(SegmentReader.java:752)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.MultiSegmentReader.docFreq(MultiSegmentReader.java:377)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.docFreq(IndexSearcher.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Similarity.idf(Similarity.java:457)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery$TermWeight.(TermQuery.java:44)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery.createWeight(TermQuery.java:146)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.(BooleanQuery.java:185)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.createWeight(BooleanQuery.java:360)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Query.weight(Query.java:95)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.(Hits.java:85)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:61)
        at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.transaction.support.AbstractTransactionProcessor.findByQuery(AbstractTransactionProcessor.java:146)
        at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.transaction.support.AbstractSearchTransactionProcessor.performFind(AbstractSearchTransactionProcessor.java:59)
        at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.transaction.search.SearchTransactionProcessor.find(SearchTransactionProcessor.java:50)
        at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.LuceneSearchEngine.find(LuceneSearchEngine.java:352)
        at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.LuceneSearchEngineQuery.hits(LuceneSearchEngineQuery.java:188)
        at org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompassQuery.hits(DefaultCompassQuery.java:199)